# VB.NET Backgroundworker only show loading form once?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2015, backgroundworker, loading

I have a button on a form which basically get data from my database as below.

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                   Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Loading_Screen.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

The loading screen is called after my code (obtain data from database) is run in backgroundworker. 
When backgroundworker is done, I close the loading form as below

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) 
                             Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
    SDA.Update(dataTable)
    ToolStripLabel1.Text = "RESULT : " + DataGridView1.RowCount.ToString
    Loading_Screen.Close()
End Sub
```

This only works when I started the application for the first time. Whenever I click the button again, the loading form will not show anymore but the code still runs fine. Any idea?

The loading form has no code at all, just a running progress bar every time it is loaded.

What I have done but no luck :

1. Me.Refresh() the main form after calling loading form.
2. Me.Refresh() the loading form when on load function.
3. Tried loadingform.hide() instead of show()
4. Tried both show() and showdialog()
5. Tried creating new instance of the loading form.
6. Me.dispose() loading form on closing function
7. Me.dispose() main form on closing function

   8. Setting loading form as top most.

**UPDATE (I will keep updating my progress here)**

As many of you asked to create a new instance, here is what I already did

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    ldScreen = New Loading_Screen()
    ldScreen.ShowDialog()
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Then, in run completed,

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
    SDA.Update(dataTable)
    ToolStripLabel1.Text = "RESULT : " + DataGridView1.RowCount.ToString
    ldScreen.Close()
    BackgroundWorker1.Dispose()
End Sub
```

In my loading form, the code is only this

```
Private Sub Loading_Screen_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Me.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub Loading_Screen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2**

By stripping out most of my code and putting system thread sleep in backgroundworker do work, the loading form shows up properly. So here is my code in backgroundworkerdowork on what is actually happening.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Connect2Database()
    Try
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "Select * from kup_table" 'Load full database into gridview
        SDA.SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        SDA.Fill(dataTable)
        bSource.DataSource = dataTable
        mySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        If mySqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            mySqlConn.Close()
        End If
    Finally
        mySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
    'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
End Sub
```

And here is the Connect2Database function codes

```
Private Sub Connect2Database()
    sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
    dataTable = New DataTable
    SDA = New MySqlDataAdapter
    bSource = New BindingSource
    Try
        dataTable.Clear()
        mySqlConn.ConnectionString = connString
        sqlCommand.Connection = mySqlConn
        mySqlConn.Open()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        If mySqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            mySqlConn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

**UPDATE 3**

What I have noticed is that when my `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` is not commented, the loading screen will show up normally. But if I changed it to `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)`, loading screen does not shows up. Why is this happening? Code runs super fast after the first time?

Comment: @bonCodigo Just read it. It doesn't seem to relate to my question. In background worker do work, I only do my code stuff. Nothing to do with visual appearance.

Comment: Is Loading_Screen an actual instance of the class of the form you're wanting to show, or is it just a reference to the type itself.

Comment: @DavidY Not sure what you meant. I did ldscreen as new Loading_Screen then ldscreen.ShowDialog(). In the Loading_Screen_FormClosing I wrote me.dispose(). In the main form backgroundworker_runcompleted i just add ldscreen.close() at the end

Comment: The Close() call assigned the Loading_Screen.DialogResult property.  You forgot to set it back to None.  Just don't do it this way, keeping a form object around for no good reason is wasteful.  Create a new one whenever you need it with the *new* operator.  And call Dispose() when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant How do I set it back to none? Btw, I have updated the question with what I did. Am I doing it right for now?

Comment: I can't repro your issue — I get a loading form every time with your code..  Calling Me.Dispose inside the FormClosing event won't accomplish anything, the form is already disposing at the time.  Likewise, calling Refresh inside the load event won't do anything either, the form isn't visible yet.

Comment: @LarsTech Tried cleaning the solution, restarting VS, all did not fix it. No idea what else to do

Comment: Start stripping out code.  Comment out the data code, replace with just a Thread.Sleep(5000) to mimic something happening in the background thread.  Keep removing code until you get down to the bare minimum that just shows the loading form every time you click the button.  Then start adding code back in until it doesn't work to isolate the issue.  The problem is somewhere in code you didn't post, so it's hard to help beyond these little tidbits.

Comment: @LarsTech But the first application start is working fine. I tried using breakpoints too, code just run though it without any problems as well. Really no idea why this is causing. VS crashed while breakpoint running once. Now gonna try again by stripping the code.

Comment: @LarsTech I just did stripping out my codes and place system thread sleep. The loading form shows up perfectly. So I have updated the question at UPDATE 2 for what my code actually do.

Answer (score 0):

This is because calling `Close()` disposes the Form. So either you have to create a new instance of the form every time, or you need to use `Hide()`.  Judging by your question, I think you want the former.

Comment: In my loading form onClosing function, I put me.hide() but still no luck in showing the form again. Always the first run is showing. Second time clicking the button not showing

Comment: Tried creating new instance as well. Not working though.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to create a new instance of the form?

`Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                   Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    Dim frm As New Loading_Screen
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    frm.ShowDialog()
End Sub`